# Is it correct to fill sets contained in vector?

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector, stl, set

I have a `vector<set<int>> v(10);`. Each set can be filled by some data. Then I insert integers to randomly sets, e.g. `v[5].insert(99);`. Can it cause undefined behavior?

Comment: Not as long as `v` containts at least six values.

Comment: Show more code. There's nothing wrong with the snippet shown here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was in another place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only if you go out of bounds of the vector.

If your `vector` has at least 6 elements, then `v[5].insert(99);` is well defined.

To be sure that you don't, you can use the [`at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at) accessor function:

```
 v.at(5).insert(99);
```

Which will throw a `std::out_of_range` exception if you try to access past the end of the array.

Comment: Aren't sets going one by one in memory?

Comment: @Pavel The only potential undefined behavior is accessing the vector, not inserting into the sets.

Comment: @Pavel, you are accessing the vector, and inserting into the set. Inserting into the set is not undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Barmar, I changed `[5]` to `.at(5)` but debugger still catches `SIGSEGV` at the line, not `out_of_range`

Comment: Not sure why you're getting any error, since you declared the vector to hold 10 elements with `v(10)`.

Comment: @Barmar, it also shows where `SIGSEGV` appeared (in calling stack), it's call of `operator new` in `new_allocator.h`

Comment: Should I search for UB cause somewhere before?

Comment: You should post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Barmar, I know about MCVE but I can't reduce my code. Is it correct to post all algorithm and problem input?

Comment: We really don't like to get huge amounts of code. But you need to post something if you want help with it. Have you tried stepping through the debugger, or using `valgrind`?

Comment: @Barmar, I tried stepping using the debugger, but all looked okay and `SIGSEGV` suddenly appeared at the line wit `insert`. What about `valgrind`, I've read about it but don't know how to install it

Comment: I'm sure the documentation at valgrind.org explains how to install it.

Comment: @Barmar, the problem was really at another place. I used `v[a].erase(v[b].begin(); v[b].end());` trying to remove all elements presents in `v[b]` from `v[a]` but `erase` work differently :)
Can it be useful for anyone or I can just remove the question now?

Comment: @Pavel is your variable really `vector<set<int>>` or is it more complex than that? It's easy to simplify the problem *too* much.

Comment: @Pavel I don't think you'll be able to remove the question, since it has an answer posted. But the question probably isn't useful, so you should flag it for closing.

Comment: @Barmar, I've flagged it but it showed that it need 50 more flags to close o_O

Comment: @Barmer, can you start a conversation next time. My inbox is on fire!